# How replicate table header when a table is forwarded to the next page using htmlconverter

Tags: itext7

this subject has been asked few time for pdf creation. My problem is different because I use htmlconverter to create a pdf from an html.
So my html has a lot of big tables and I would like to have the header of the table replicated when the table is forwarded to the next page.
Is it possible to do it with htmlconverter???
Thanks in advance
kor6k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are repeated automatically if they are inside a `<thead>` of your `<table>`. For instance:

```
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>abbr</th>
    <th>capital</th>
    <th>most populous city</th>
    <th>population</th>
    <th>square miles</th>
    <th>time zone 1</th>
    <th>time zone 2</th>
    <th>dst</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>ALABAMA</td>
    <td>AL</td>
    <td>Montgomery</td>
    <td>Birmingham</td>
    <td>4,708,708</td>
    <td>52,423</td>
    <td>CST (UTC-6)</td>
    <td>EST (UTC-5)</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ALASKA</td>
    <td>AK</td>
    <td>Juneau</td>
    <td>Anchorage</td>
    <td>698,473</td>
    <td>656,425</td>
    <td>AKST (UTC-09) </td>
    <td>HST (UTC-10) </td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```